# 301 redirect or URL redirection in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the query string URL into my own URL in the .htaccess file. I am not finding any solution, please help me out in this. I want to redirect my URL with query string `https://example.com/?p=3842`  to `https://example.com/`  like that what I want to redirect it. Any Help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples of using query string matching.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=3842
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Be sure and let me know how this works for you.